# Difference between 'web3-react' and ''@web3-react/core''

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

I am trying to understand how popular projects works.

Here is what i've found in uniswap interface's source code:

https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-interface/blob/master/src/hooks/index.ts:

```
import { useWeb3React as useWeb3ReactCore } from '@web3-react/core'
```

And here is what i've found in aave interface's source code:

https://github.com/aave/uniswap-frontend/blob/beta/src/hooks/index.js

```
import { useWeb3Context } from 'web3-react'
```

What is the difference between those 2 libraries ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Most likely historically differently named package

Comment: What is the newest one ? And to be sure, can you confirm me we can install with "yarn add web3" ?

Comment: My comment was speculative, as I hope it is up to you to verify this from the authors of packages from yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to npmjs.com web3-react is the parent of web3-react/core and both pages point to the same github repo:
[web3-react](https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion，`web3-react` is the former version, and `@web3-react/core` is the current version.

`web3-react` end up with version `5.0.5`
`@web3-react/core` starts with version `6.0.0-beta.0`